# assign random integer to each group in a dataframe

Tags: r, random, group-by

Given a data frame with three different observations for each individual, I'm trying to assign a  unique random integer to each unique individual.
`df <- data.frame(sample = 1:15, ID = rep(1:5, times = 3))`

```
     sample ID
1       1  1
2       2  2
3       3  3
4       4  4
5       5  5
6       6  1
7       7  2
8       8  3
9       9  4
10     10  5
11     11  1
12     12  2
13     13  3
14     14  4
15     15  5
```

In this case, I want each ID to have a random value 'newvar' between 1 and 5.

I've tried

`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(newvar = sample(5, n(), replace = FALSE))`

which doesn't keep the new variable the same within each ID, and

`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(newvar = sample.int(n()))`

which gives a random number between 1 and 3 within each group, and

`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(newvar = sample(5, replace = FALSE))`

which doesn't work as it wants newvar to be size 1 or 3, not 5.

I've also tried using the levels of ID:

```
levels(df$ID) <- sample(length(levels(df$ID)))
df$newvar <- levels(df$ID)
```

This randomized the ID column and wrote it to newvar on the test df

```
    sample ID newvar
1       1  5      5
2       2  2      2
3       3  1      1
4       4  4      4
5       5  3      3
6       6  5      5
7       7  2      2
8       8  1      1
9       9  4      4
10     10  3      3
11     11  5      5
12     12  2      2
13     13  1      1
14     14  4      4
15     15  3      3
```

and on my full data set (918 observations of 306 individuals) it throws an error:

`` Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 918 rows. x Assigned data has 306 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. ``

Is there a way to get sample() to happen within the group_by command, or to get each level of ID assigned correctly to a random integer?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `base R` to `sample` the `unique` values of 'ID' and then match with the 'ID' after setting the names as the `unique` 'ID'.  This should also work when the 'ID' is not numeric or is not following a sequence starting from 1

```
un1 <- unique(df$ID)
df$newvar <- setNames(sample(un1), un1)[as.character(df$ID)]
df
#   sample ID newvar
#1       1  1      4
#2       2  2      2
#3       3  3      3
#4       4  4      5
#5       5  5      1
#6       6  1      4
#7       7  2      2
#8       8  3      3
#9       9  4      5
#10     10  5      1
#11     11  1      4
#12     12  2      2
#13     13  3      3
#14     14  4      5
#15     15  5      1
```

Comment: do we not need each id to have the same random number assigned?

Answer (score 0):

How about just subsetting a sample of length 5 by the ID?

```
df %>% mutate(newvar = sample(5)[ID])
#>    sample ID newvar
#> 1       1  1      4
#> 2       2  2      5
#> 3       3  3      3
#> 4       4  4      2
#> 5       5  5      1
#> 6       6  1      4
#> 7       7  2      5
#> 8       8  3      3
#> 9       9  4      2
#> 10     10  5      1
#> 11     11  1      4
#> 12     12  2      5
#> 13     13  3      3
#> 14     14  4      2
#> 15     15  5      1
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it most in line with the way you were thinking, this assigns a consistent sample to each ID between 1 and 5.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(newvar = sample(5, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one does what I want: copy the ID to newvar first, then sample() on the levels.

```
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df$newvar <- df$ID
levels(df$newvar) <- sample(length(levels(df$newvar)))
```

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Using levels() got what I wanted for the random numbering, but now I want to add 40 to each of the newvar numbers. If I convert the factors back to numeric, I lose the random numbers; it just starts numbering sequentially from 40. Even if I convert first to character then to numeric, same thing. Any way to lose the embedded history of these numbers?

Comment: aha! `as.numeric(as.character(df$newvar))` all in one command does the trick!